# Given an array of size $n$, return a sorted array of floor($n^k$) elements for some $k<1$

Tags: asymptotics, sorting, big-o-notation

> We are given an array of size $n$ (it is not specified if we have an integer array, a specific range or any other assumptions), which might be unsorted, and a real number as a
> constant $k<1$. We need to prove or disprove that it is possible to
> output the $\lfloor n^k \rfloor$ smallest elements of a sorted order, in $O(n)$ worst case time
> complexity.
>
> example: let $A$ be an array of size 4, and let $k=0.6$. The algorithm should output the smallest $\lfloor 4^{0.6}\rfloor \approx \lfloor2.29\rfloor = 2$ items in A in a sorted order.

I have two ideas here, one to prove the statement and one to disprove it, but not sure how can both be possible:

Disprove: Given that we are able to choose a $k<1$ as we wish, choose a $k=0.9999...$ so $\lfloor n^k \rfloor = n-1$. Assuming by contradiction that this algorithm is possible, we can sort the $n-1$ smallest elements of $A$, and then append the largest element in $O(n)$. This leads to a contradiction resulting from the lower bound for comparison based sorting in $\Omega(n\log n)$.

Prove: use the following algorithm:

1. Find $\lfloor n^k \rfloor$'s rank in the array using median of medians and partition the array using it as a pivot.
2. Preform a Heapsort on a min heap created (in $O(n)$) from the elements smaller than $\lfloor n^k \rfloor$ following the partition.

for the sorting part, calculating the time complexity might generally look like this:
As $\lfloor n^k \rfloor \le n^k$ , $\lfloor n^k \rfloor * \log(\lfloor n^k \rfloor) \le k*n^k*\log(n)$. As $k<1$ $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{k*n^k*\log(n)}{n} = \dots =0 $, so the sorting is in $o(n)$, and the entire algorithm is in $O(n).$

I think my main issue in both is understanding the asymptotic calculation vs the practical matter of sorting an array (or that my math is entirely wrong, which is an option).

What should be the correct idea/solution?

Comment: "some constant $k<1$".  Can you explain what "constant" means here? Be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Sure, updated accordingly and added an example

Comment: It is great to see an example. I claim $n$ is also a constant. At least in your example, $n=4$ is also a constant. What do you think?

Comment: Seems fair, as the hypothetical algorithm receives an initial array and some real number k, we can choose any positive integer n to represent the length of A

Comment: Would you become a register user? I am afraid I have reached my limit to help an unregistered user. Of course you do not have to register. Others may answer your question anyway.

Comment: Of course, done :)

Comment: Presumably you meant $\lfloor n^k \rfloor = \color{red}n-1$. Please fix this as it is essential to the argument.

Comment: There is no need to find the rank of $\lfloor n^k\rfloor$, build the heap in linear time.

Comment: @LearningSomeone In fact, the exercise does not require the $\lfloor n^k\rfloor$ smallest elements be returned *in a sorted order*, although the example does. I will update my answer  shortly to include that important point.

Comment: @JohnL. mistype on my end, the example was correct and the question was missing the sorted part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> a constant $k<1$

The answer depends on the understanding of the word "constant".

#### The meaning of "a constant $k$"

Here is the expected interpretation.

You are asked to answer infinitely many questions. One of them is the following.

> We are given an array of size $n$. Is it possible to output the $\lfloor n^{0.6} \rfloor$ smallest elements in $O(n)$ worst case time complexity?

The answer to the question above is, as you have proved, yes.

Another such question is the following.

> We are given an array of size $n$. Is it possible to output the $\lfloor n^{0.999} \rfloor$ smallest elements in $O(n)$ worst case time complexity?

The answer to the question above is, as you have proved, yes. As you must have noticed, I am repeating myself, except that $0.6$ has been replaced with $0.999$.

Still another such question is the following.

> We are given an array of size $n$. Is it possible to output the $\lfloor n^{\frac1{10}} \rfloor$ smallest elements in $O(n)$ worst case time complexity?

The answer is, as you have proved, yes. As you must have noticed, I am repeating myself, except that $0.6$ has been replaced with $\frac1{10}$.

It turns out that whatever number is used to substitute for $0.6$, as long as it is between $0$ and $1$ exclusive, the answer is yes. This is the expected answer.

#### Nitpicking on your proof

A vital piece is missing from the following statement.

> As $k<1$ $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{k*n^k*\log(n)}{n} = \dots =0 $, …

It should have been the following.

> As $k<1$ **is a constant with respect to $n$**, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{k*n^k*\log(n)}{n} = \dots =0 $, …

If $k$ is not a constant with respect to $n$, for example $k=\frac{\log(n-1)}{\log n}$,  that limit is no longer $0$.

On the other hand, you will probably not see the phrase "is a constant" in the official solution to this problem nor solutions to similar problems, since people will assume that phrase on that spot given the condition "a constant $k$" in the problem statement. In other words, your proof is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I’m currently thinking of the case where k is not a constant with respect to n (0.6, 0.999, etc but not logn for example). Where does my logic fail at the disprove attempt?

Comment: When you "choose a $k=0.9999...$,  so $\lfloor n^k\rfloor=n-1$",  $k$ becomes dependent on $n$, i.e., $k$ is not a constant (with respect to $n$).  $\lfloor n^k\rfloor=n-1$ will fail eventually for any constant $k<1$ when $n\to\infty$, however close $k$ is to $1$.

Comment: If $k$ is not required to be a constant with respect to $nS, then your disprove attempt is correct.

Comment: @LearningSomeone $k$ a function of $n$ is absurd. Because $m(n)=\lfloor n^{k(n)}\rfloor$ could be any number in $[0,n)$, allowing the trivial worst-case $n-1$, but also the trivial best-case $2$. For this reason, the question should have stated "for any $k$ function of $n$" to have a unique answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for more explanation and supporting my answer. I guess the downvote on my answer comes from the fact that I was too "soft" on claiming the answer depends on interpretation, although I did write what is the expected correct answer. I might update my answer to be more assertive.

Comment: I was struck by the conclusion "your proof is pretty good" when in fact the OP is inconclusive. So I have been wondering what you answered in the end.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What I mean is, apparently,  the "prove attempt" out of the two attempts is pretty good. It is not "all of your two attempts including the disprove attempt" are good.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I will update "your proof" in two places to "your prove attempt" shortly since the former can be misleading. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The "disproof" is wrong, and the answer is positive.

Because there is no $k$ such that

$$\lfloor n^k\rfloor=n-1$$ for all $n$. You may *not* assume that $k$ is a function of $n$, this would amount to saying "sort *any number* of smallest elements".

On the opposite, with $m=\lfloor n^k\rfloor$, getting the $m$ smallest elements with Heapsort will take time $O(n+m\log n)$ and for *any constant* $k<1$,

$$\lfloor n^k\rfloor\log n\le n^k\log n=o(n).$$

This is because

$$\log n=o(n^\epsilon)$$ for any $\epsilon>0$.